# Need more than 0 values to unpack

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some code:

```
text = ''
for key, value in d:
    text += k + ' ' + str(v) + '\n'
file = open('ATM Data', 'w')
file.write(text)
file.close()
```

and when it runs it raises a

```
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

but actually I do have some things in my dictionary.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What is `d` value or type?

Comment: Looks like you also have a bug where you use "k" and "v" where you meant "key" and "value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iterator of a dictionary only iterates over the keys, thus either you can use the `items` (portable), or just iterate over the key and fetch the values:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    text += key + ' ' + str(value) + '\n'
```

or

```
for key in d:
    text += key + ' ' + str(d[key]) + '\n'
```

Notice that you can get much more performance by using `join` with generator expression however:

```
text = '\n'.join('{} {}'.format(key, value) for key, value in d.items()) + '\n'
```

Answer (score 3):

If `d` is dictionary then you have to use `d.items()` or `d.iteritems()` to get `key, value` as pair.